# Importing Java generics in groovy for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl.BindCaller.T
import java.util.List

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Shared
```

This one is strange to me because the code itself seems to work just fine. I've imported a project into my eclipse that uses an import of the BindCaller.T library. This compiles fine using jenkins and maven, but eclipse (oxygen) seems to have problems with it. I'm wondering if anyone has a suggestion for what configurations might be off.

The error I'm receiving is

> The type java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl is not visible

Eclipse Oxygen with Groovy Compiler Version 2.5.0-beta-2 and Java 1.7

Comment: `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl` has 'package' visibility so it can only be used in the other classes in the 'java.lang.invoke' package.

Comment: Well, that's good to know. Crazy that made it into production